# What does the logical statement ¬P < ¬Q mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know the "¬" sign means "not" but I am a little confused by the sign that resembles "<". What exactly would that mean?

Any help?

Comment: Probably it means what it literally means when you assign $0$ and $1$ values to false and true statements. But then the statement would become $P\land\neg Q$.

Comment: Without context, it is hard give an explanation, perhaps P and Q are elements from an algebra, in these context, make sense P < Q.

Comment: Are you talking about $\subset$?

Comment: Please, check on the [List of logic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols).

Comment: The $\subset$ symbol is a leftward material implication, and it is the same as writing $\leftarrow$. The $\subset$ is generally favoured by philosophers, while the $\leftarrow$ is favoured by mathematicians (although I think most mathematicians would prefer to flip the whole expression around and write $\rightarrow$ instead).